# What does the '+new' mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Looking through the jQuery source in the function `now()` I see the following:

```
function now(){
    return +new Date;
}
```

I've never seen the plus operator prepended to the new operator like this.  What does it do?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Nicolás and Brian are right, but if you're curious about how it works, `+new Date();` is equivalent to `(new Date()).valueOf();`, because the [unary `+` operator](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.4.6) gets the *value of* its operand expression, and then converts it [`ToNumber`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-9.3).

You could add a `valueOf` method on any object and use the unary + operator to return a *numeric representation* of your object, e.g.:

```
var productX = {
  valueOf : function () {
    return 500; // some "meaningful" number
  }
};

var cost = +productX; // 500
```

Comment: Since `valueOf()` is returning a number isn't prepending the unary + operator basically unnecessary in the above example?  I would think it would be more meaningful if valueOf() returned `"500"`.

Comment: @Darrel, are you looking at different code example than I am? I don't see any edits to this post, so your comment seems strangely out of touch and irrelevant, but almost like the post could have been edited after the comment.

Comment: @Breton The "Since valueOf() is..." question is in response to @CMS's answer to my original question.

Comment: @Darrell: Well, it depends on the semantics of how do you will use your object, e.g. if you return a `String`, the unary `+` operator will work as expected (because internally it invokes `ToNumber`), but if you use the binary `+` operator, on two objects that its `valueOf` return a `String`, a String concatenation will be made, instead of a sum...

Answer (score 10):

I think the unary plus operator applied to anything would cause it to be converted into a number.

Comment: Hm, does + always convert the expression into a number? + is a valid operator for both strings and numbers. 1* is usually used to force an argument into a number.

Comment: @Ernelli, + is only a valid string operator when it's used as a binary operator. The unary + operator only applies to numbers, so it converts the same way that 1* does.

Comment: Ernelli: See CMS's answer below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983040/what-does-the-new-mean-in-javascript/1983109#1983109. Unary `+` seems to always convert its operand to a number, while binary `+` can be used on strings.

Answer (score 9):

It converts the [`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Date) into an integer, giving you the current number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970.

Comment: @Brian IE will do that from time to time. ;)

Comment: Actually, it's a WebKit nightly build... I suppose I should expect that from a nightly build.

Comment: Good excuse ;-) I wonder who upvoted your comment, someone must have seen you relaunching the browser! ;-)

Comment: That's kind of creepy... who is watching me post on Stack Overflow? What are they doing in my house? o_O

Answer (score 1):

```
function now(){
    return +new Date;
}
```

This function means the developer is clever.

---

```
function now(){
    return (new Date()).getTime();
}
```

This function means, get the current time [in milliseconds since 1970](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime). And the developer has some mercy for those who wish to understand WTF is going on.