# catching seconds on MouseClicked Event

Tags: java, mouseevent

Is there a way to take the time in seconds or in milliseconds, between the clicked of the mouse button and the release of this one.

I used this feature, but does not right for me

```
public void mouseClicked (MouseEvent me) {
   long time=me.getWhen();
  // other stuff
}
```

some help?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1360818/javascript-how-to-measure-the-milliseconds-between-mousedown-and-mouseup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It didn't work for you because getWhen() returns the time in miliseconds of when that event occured, not the time the event lasted. 
This code works for me:

```
long mousePressed;
long mouseReleased;
long mousePressTime;

@Override
public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
    mousePressed = e.getWhen();
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
    mouseReleased = e.getWhen();

    mousePressTime = mouseReleased - mousePressed;

    System.out.println("PRESS TIME "+mousePressTime);
}
```

Comment: +1, thanks you so much,i 've tried several type of implementations,this is much fine.